# Pulling Instagram feed into a nested Div using ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, instagram

I have a div that's nested in two other divs but isn't pulling in the Instagram feed via the ID, although when I take the div out and have it on it's own it displays.

How can I change the code either in the js file or the HTML for get it to display when its nested

Here's the related part of the JS file...

```
 $(function() {
var cmdURL, embedImage, onPhotoLoaded, param, tag_name, userid,
param = {
access_token: '******************', // feel free to change it with your own access token
count: 10 // the total number of images
},
tag = 'Gezza', // your user id. you can find this one out by looking into one of your pictures uri
tag_name = '#photowall',
cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?callback=?';
```

And here's the HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 home3block">
          <div class="block">
              <img src="assets/images/instagram-logo.gif">

              <!-- START PHOTOWALL -->
              <div id="photowall">
              </div>
              <!-- CLOSE PHOTOWALL -->


         </div>
      </div>
```

I need the #photowall to be inside both col-md-6 and block divs

Comment: Depending on your goals; a real quick an easy solution: http://snapwidget.com/

Comment: this is a good plug-in but it doesnt work for me as its not responsive in Bootstrap

Comment: Use multiple instances of it between various defined media querie resolutions, playa. Show / Hide